# Mule CloudHub deployment API Autodiscovery failing with code 412

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Mule 3.8.4.
Trying to deploy App to cloud and getting this error:

> Unable to create API testapp with version 1.0. Error: Server return wrong status code. Status code: 412. Details: Precondition Failed

Org credentials (id and secret) are set in Studio and passed validation.

Autodiscovery implementation:

```
<api-platform-gw:api apiName="${api.name}" version="${api.version}" flowRef="main"  create="true" doc:name="API v1 Autodiscovery" apikitRef="config"/>
```

Tried to delete and recreate from scratch - same error.

Comment: Can you confirm how you have set the client id and secret? Can you show how you have set the properties?

Comment: @RyanCarter,
Properties were set through Runtime Manager:

anypoint.platform.analytics_base_uri=https://analytics-ingest.anypoint.mulesoft.com
anypoint.platform.client_id=********************************
anypoint.platform.coreservice_base_uri=https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts
anypoint.platform.client_secret=********************************

Comment: @dreezt check this out --> http://www.acesoa.com/2018/07/05/api-manager-auto-discovery/ step by step guide on auto discovery and make sure you have not skipped any part or missing something.

Comment: @satishchennupati, Thank you for the link, but I did not missed steps. I wondering if it is still possible to auto-create API during deployment w/o involving Exchange. P.S. I'm using Mule3, not a big difference, but though.

Answer (score 0):

If your Anypoint Platform organization was migrated to the Crowd release, the `create` attribute is no longer supported. Try removing it.